# Dumping multiple objects in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, pickle, dump

When I tried to dump a second object into a binary file, it keeps rewriting the first. I want to have many objects in the file.
Here's the code:

```
import pickle

def create_file(obj):
      Fo=open ('pay.txt','wb')
      pickle.dump(obj,Fo)
      Fo.close()
```

Basically, as and when the user wants to add a new entry, this function is called. 
Given this, I can't use a list and dump everything at once.
Could you please tell me my error or suggest alternative code.

Comment: Have you tried changing 'wb' to 'a' or 'ab' ?

Comment: No I didn't! That was the error! Thank you. It's been long and I completely forgot about append mode.

Comment: Cool. Accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the file mode.

```
import pickle

def create_file(obj):
  Fo=open ('pay.txt','ab')
  pickle.dump(obj,Fo)
  Fo.close()
```